# Camel-jetty component : use of available options

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I am using the recipientList tag in my route as shown below. The bean findCallbackUrl will return a String which is my destination address. i.e i will be making a POST request to this endpoint . For example i may have a server listening at http://localhost:8080/acceptcallbacks .

```
 <recipientList>
     <method ref="findCallbackUrl"/> 
 </recipientList>
```

So when the String(destination) returned from the findCallbackUrl bean is jetty:http://localhost:8080/acceptcallback , the POST works fine.

However when some of the option mentioned in the [Camel-jetty component](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html) are used so issues are seen. when the destination returned is jetty:http://localhost:8080/acceptcallbacks?enableJmx=false or jetty:http://localhost:8080/acceptcallbacks?disableStreamCache=false the POST works fine. However if the returned string is jetty:http://localhost:8080/acceptcallbacks?chunked=false , the call becomes a GET request .

Not sure what is happening here. If the Camel-jetty options are not to be used in the way they have been used above , for options enableJmx or disableStreamCache or some other options , the resulting destination URL should have been http://localhost:8080/acceptcallbacks?enableJmx=false which is a GET request.

Can chunked=false be used for producer as well as consumer endpoints or is it only for consumer endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Selection of http method in **jetty** depends on In Body of camel exchange, or on `CamelHttpMethod` header.

Look at source code of class `org.apache.camel.component.http.helper.HttpHelper`, method `createMethod`:

```
public static HttpMethods createMethod(Exchange exchange, HttpEndpoint endpoint, boolean hasPayload) throws URISyntaxException {
    // compute what method to use either GET or POST
    HttpMethods answer;
    HttpMethods m = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, HttpMethods.class);
    if (m != null) {
        // always use what end-user provides in a header
        answer = m;
    } else if (hasPayload) {
        // use POST if we have payload
        answer = HttpMethods.POST;
    } else {
        // fallback to GET
        answer = HttpMethods.GET;
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Now look at the call of this method in class `org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpProducer`:

`HttpMethods methodToUse = HttpHelper.createMethod(exchange, getEndpoint(), exchange.getIn().getBody() != null);`

IMHO options don't matter. Check `exchange.getIn().getBody()` before request to HTTP, or you can reset header `CamelHttpMethod`.